# Getting deeper nested value of [String : AnyObject] in swift 3

Tags: swift3

I am getting user's Facebook profile details by signing in the user through Firebase Facebook Authentication.

The nested array looks like this:

```
 ["picture": { 
     data = {
        "is_silhouette" = 0;
        url = "someUrl"; 
    };
}, "name": James, "last_name": Bond, "email": james_bond007@hotmail.com, "id": 10210066243726102, "first_name": James, "gender": male]
```

Im struggling to get the value of picture url.

I tried something like this but it doesn't work:

```
var fbPhotoUrl: URL?
self.fbPhotoUrl = self.FBUserDict["picture"]!["data"]!["url"] as? URL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
if let picture = FBUserDict["picture"] as? [String: Any], let data = picture["data"] as? [String: Any], let urlString = data["url"] as? String, let url = URL(string: urlString) {

    self.fbPhotoUrl = url
}
```

Comment: I copy pasted your code and still the same @LeoDabus

Comment: `print(self.fbPhotoUrl?.absoluteString ?? "")`

Comment: @LeoDabus print(self.fbPhotoUrl ?? "") worked. thanx alot man

Comment: Can you please tell me what the ?? "" does??

Comment: ?? nil coalescing operator to print "" in case of nil. You should take a look at it. You need to use it to provide default value in case of nil